# Graph Explorer: Need admin approval

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
I am trying to call sendMail in graph and received error:
Graph explorer (official site) needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I understand that I need to ask an admin, but I don't know who to ask or what the procedure is like. My tenant is "Microsoft"

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Mail.Send does not require the administrator's consent. Have you granted other permissions to the application that require the administrator's consent?

Answer (score 1):

The application requires one or more permissions which only Global Admin can consent for. There are some permissions for which standard users can provide consent but if the application needs high-level permission with which any changes can be made to the directory, the above message is displayed and only the Global Administrator can consent to those permissions.

So you would need to contact Global Administrator to provide consent. for microsoft.com tenant, you can open a request [here](https://microsoft.service-now.com/sp%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B). Please refer to a [similar question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/37875/application-needs-permission-to-access-resources-i.html) it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You have granted the application permission without the admin consent. The easiest way is to redirect the user to the administrator consent endpoint, then log in with the administrator account, and click the `Accept` button to grant the administrator consent for your application.

You need to request the URL in your browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/adminconsent?client_id={client_id}
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)